# Not able to filter out required property in Azure TSI Gen1 Get Events API response

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

I am using the below request body to fetch only the required property values.

```
  "searchSpan": {
    "from": {
      "dateTime": "2021-11-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "to": {
      "dateTime": "2021-11-20T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  "predicateString": "[Params.Name] = 'power'",

  "take": 100
  }
}
```

The URL is like below:

https://12345678a-bcde-3e91-blah-2292933292aa.env.timeseries.azure.com/events?api-version=2016-12-12

Despite specifying the required property the response returns all properties as if it has not seen the predicate string. What might I be doing wrong?

```
{
    "warnings": [],
    "events": [
        {
            "schema": {
                "rid": 0,
                "$esn": "my-event-hub",
                "properties": [
                    {
                        "name": "mytimestamp",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Params.Name",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Params.Value",
                        "type": "Double"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "$ts": "2021-11-20T10:01:50Z",
            "values": [
                "2021-11-20T10:01:50Z",
                "energy",
                60            
             ]
        },
        {
            "schemaRid": 0,
            "$ts": "2021-11-20T10:01:50Z",
            "values": [
                "2021-11-20T10:01:50Z",
                "power",
                10
            ]
        },
        {
            "schemaRid": 0,
            "$ts": "2021-11-20T10:01:50Z",
            "values": [
                "2021-11-20T10:01:50Z",
                "strength",
                200
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

### Edit

I'm getting "Properties count error" in the TSI overview page. This might quite be the root cause but I don't know for sure

"For Time Series Insights environment ABC: You have used all 641/600 properties in your environment".

Comment: Did you try using different [Predicate String Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/gen1-query-syntax#predicate-string-expressions)?

Comment: Yes, but the results are same